# The position and rotation attributes are not updating with SetAttribute in aframe 0.8.0

Tags: aframe, webvr

My component is meant to create a new entity on check, which it does, and it adds MOST of the attributes but not rotation and position. I see that this appeared to be a problem is versions before 0.5.0 but I am using 0.8.0 and it is still not updating. Any ideas?

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('new-room', {
  schema: {
    on: {type: 'string'},
    rotation: {type: 'string'},
    target: {type: 'selector'},
    iconposition: {type: 'string'},
    iconrotation: {type: 'string'}
  },

  init: function () {

    // Do something when component first attached.
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;

    el.addEventListener(data.on, function () {
        // Set image.
        data.target.setAttribute('rotation', data.rotation);

        // Remove all room icons
        var entityEl = document.querySelector('.icons');
        entityEl.parentNode.removeChild(entityEl);


        // Adjust room icons
    var entityEl = document.createElement('a-entity');
        document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(entityEl);
        entityEl.setAttribute('geometry', {primitive: 'plane', height: '1', width: '1'});
        entityEl.setAttribute('material', {shader: 'flat', src: '#thumb', transparent: 'true', opacity: '.3'});
        entityEl.setAttribute('class','icons');
        entityEl.setAttribute('position',data.iconposition);
    document.querySelector('a-scene').flushToDOM(true);

    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It needs link with simple runnable example to reproduce. Also use 0.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `data.rotation` being set? Because you are passing in the same object, it does not recognize it as an update. We prescribe to update rotation in the docs using `object3D.rotation` like `el.object3D.rotation.set(x, y, z)` or `el.object3D.rotation.copy(vec3)`.